# Same Column Size

Tags: css

in My CMS I have a row with 4 column. each column has a picture, title, excerpt of content (50 words limit), date and button link to complete story.

The size of images, titles, excerpt (if the story less than 50 words) are not fixed. I want each columns which data come from database become fix in size the button at the bottom and image at the top and for fix the size white spaces spread  in column space. I have tried many ways (bulma, css grid) and didn't get the perfect result. Tkx for guide.

[image]

Comment: Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and you will get all the cols with same height, then set its position to relative and buttons to absolute and set bottom position of buttons to 0 (or 10px or whatever you want). You can wrap images to the div wrapper and set its height to static size (maybe not the best solution, but will also helps you with extreme tall images).

Comment: set a fixed height of text div

Comment: Debute's comment is the way: try using flexbox (along with Autoprefixer).

Comment: See my answer for a flexbox solution. To make the button appear on the bottom, use `flex: 1` on the text, to make it take up as much space as available, pushing the button to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the following jquery plugin:
 https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to do this:

**My code example:**

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.block {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you could use the new [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), however browser compatibility will be sub-optimal as of now. Using Flex Box will also achieve what you wanted. See this snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
}

article {
  margin: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col">
    <article>
      <h1>
        Title of my post
      </h1>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <p>
        Some random text to fill in as the content of this article...
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <article>
      <h1>
        Title of my post
      </h1>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <p>
        Some random text to fill in as the content of this article... Some random text to fill in as the content of this article.. .
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <article>
      <h1>
        Title of my post
      </h1>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <p>
        Some random text to fill in as the content of this article.. .Some random text to fill in as the content of this article.. . Some random text to fill in as the content of this article.. .
      </p>
    </article>
  </div> 
  <div class="col">
    <article>
      <h1>
        Title of my post
      </h1>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <p>
        Some random text to fill in as the content of this article...
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your third option is to use JavaScript, like the following Gist I made for browsers that do not support flexbox: [Gist with usage example.](https://gist.github.com/danielkov/8860dd32b876857bd9f9a5cabf2d5505)

Finally you could use `display: table`, however it is not very reliable and somewhat out-dated.